# Unable to start docker mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running this following command

```
docker start mongodb
```

getting the error as follows, how to fix it.

```
Error response from daemon: failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpointCnt: Key not found in store
Error: failed to start containers: mongodb
```

Comment: please add more information. It's not clear from the given information. Also, did you tried to fetch the image again?

Comment: I am trying to start MongoDB using Docker, yesterday it was working fine, but today morning it started throwing errors like above

Comment: Try to fetch the image again. It seems it can't fetch the image from the registry.

Comment: Try fetching the image again. This looks to be related: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2356

Comment: I got a solution, I removed MongoDB in my physical system and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data directory on your host system, e.g. `/var/lib/data`.
Start your mongo container like this:

$ `docker run --name my-mongo-container -v /var/lib/data:/data/db -d mongo:latest`

The `-v /var/lib/data:/data/db` part of the command mounts the `/var/lib/data` directory from the underlying host system as `/data/db` inside the container, where MongoDB by default will write its data files.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The docker seems unable to get the image. Try running `docker images` command to see if the image is still there. Then use `docker search mongodb` and run the latest official image from the list. This should resolve the issue.